# <![CDATA[ ]]> tag is missing after sending request from WCF test client

Tags: c#, wcf, cdata

I am creating WCF app on C# where there is only one input parameter: XML string.

I try to send request to my app from WCF test client. Sometimes i need to use <![CDATA[ ]>> wrap inside my tags.

Here is simple example of xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
  <Contract>
    <ContractData>
       <Name><![CDATA[M&M's]]></Name>
    </ContractData>  
  </Contract>
```

I place this inside WCF test client and send a request.

When i look under debug at my C# code i see that my method gets this string, but CDATA section is not there:

```
public MyResponse GetContract(string xml) //<--- Here XML is already without CDATA section
{
   //Code to deserialize and generate response
}
```

So i get an Deserialization Exception, because '&' symbol need to be covered in CDATA. With Name tag without '&' symbol there is no exception.

I tried SoapUI and trial WCF Strom, the same effect. Why WCF clients are eating my CDATA part and how to make them stop doing it?

Comment: Where is your code where you serialize your data to XML? Or are you using a client library you don't have the source-code for? Why are you so sure that absolutely need to use `CDATA` instead of (far simpler, and _just-as-correct_) XML-encoding of `&` as `&amp;`) - WCF services should be able to handle XML-encoded entities the same as CDATA - (Personally, I've only ever had to use explicit `CDATA` when working with external services that (stupidly) do stuff like `xml.Substring( xml.IndexOf( "<![CDATA[" ) + 9 )`, eww)

Comment: My web-service is called from another app which i can't change anyhow, they are generating <![CDATA[ ]]> for XML parts that have special symbols, so i need to find what's wrong on my side to keep this tag after request is send.

I also tried to use XML-encoding in WCF test client: lt;![CDATA[ M&amp;M]]&amp;gt; but client also strips them when i look under debug

Comment: Is this whole string  `![CDATA[M&M's]]` can't be obtained? Have you ever tried using an escape character `\`.